# when changing the excel file format to CSV , it removes the zero number at the begining of cells

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2010

I have an excel file, including some names and mobile numbers.
I want to add these numbers to my phone contacts and I should first change the format to CSV.

The problem is that when I change the format, the zero number at the beginning of cells is being removed.
I tried format cells--->text , but it didn't work too.
also I tried international numbers (+98 ...) but in this case the "+" is being dropped and the problem remains.

Do you have any suggestion for me?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwvyU.jpg)

Comment: How are you converting the Excel file to a CSV? If you are choosing the right tool / mean then your phone numbers (which are currently stored as text) will remain as such. Just ensure to give Excel not the option of converting them to a number.

Answer (score 0):

numbers do not have leading zeros, that is formatting
if you need to have them, then you should make those cells formatted as strings, then the export will include the leading 0 as well
but maybe simpler is to make them international numbers and use the notation +1… (example for USA).

[international telephone codes](https://www.howtocallabroad.com/results.php?callfrom=canada&callto=united_states)

Comment: While you are correct that number can not have leading zeros it might seems like that to a user if the number format is set to something like `00000`. In that case the number 7 would be display as `00007`. This is just a side-note because your answer might indicate to a reader that it is not possible to show a number with `0`s up front.

Comment: @w01f ,how can I format cells as strings? I tried format cells--->text but it doesn't work yet.